# After adding Category ViewModel., An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

CategoryVM:::::

public class CategoryVM
{
public Category Category { get; set; } = new Category();

```
    public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; } = new List<Category>();
}
```

---

CategoryController::::

private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
public CategoryController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
{
_unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
}

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        CategoryVM categoryVM = new CategoryVM();
        categoryVM.Categories = _unitOfWork.Category.GetAll();
        return View(categoryVM);
    }
```

---

the code was working fine before adding viewmodel but after adding this I gonna face viewmodel error like:::

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'ModelLibrary.ViewModel.CategoryVM', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ModelLibrary.Models.Category]'.

Answer (score 0):

you have to fix an Index view model, instead of Category should be

```
@model CategoryVM 

.... fix the html data binding accordingly
```

or if you don't use a Category in your view, you can change model

```
@model List<Category>

.... fix the html data binding accordingly
```

but in this case you will have to change the action code too

```
 var model = _unitOfWork.Category.GetAll();
  return View(model)
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct you just need to:

```
@model IEnumerable<ModelLibrary.Models.Category>
```

Replace by given blew code because we already made list in ViewModel and upper code is also printing list that's because exception hendling error appearing:

```
@model ModelLibrary.ViewModel.CategoryVM
```